# How to access offline SmartStore data with native iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, salesforce, sfdc

I am using native SalesForce iOS SDK which stores data in offline SmartStores and synchronize with the server. If internet is not available it stores data in offline SmartStores allows to sync with SalesForce server when internet is available.

While internet is not available I want to fetch records from offline SmartStore those were not synced to SalesForce server.

Is there any way to access that data stored in offline SmartStores?